# Is it possible to get execution time of each line with gcov?

Tags: c++, code-coverage, gcov

Is it possible to get the execution time of each line with gcov?
Does GCC have such a compilation option? Is any other tool which can generate such information?

Comment: Have you tried perf?

Comment: @Taekahn As I got perf provides statistics for methods only

Comment: perf annotate will show you the performance statistics along side your code.

Answer (score 0):

You can run the code in question in Valgrind, then view the results in KCachegrind (screenshot attached). You can see the source annotated; it's not perfect, but it does the job.
[image]